# Databse connection function change from MYSQLI to MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I was wondering if anyone can help me with changing this to a mysql connection and not mysqli please

```
  public function __construct() {
    $this->dbConnection = new mysqli($this->_dbHost, $this->_dbUsername, 
        $this->_dbPassword, $this->_databaseName);

    if ($this->dbConnection->connect_error) {
      die('Connection error.');
    }
  }
```

Its part of a tutorial but i havent used mysqli before and cant work it out to fit my needs.

Cheers
Jonny

Comment: but why to use mysql which does not have support and is deprecated ??

Comment: @MixedVeg did you downvote me?

Comment: Nopes just asked you something :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not recommend you to use mysql_* functions because they have been deprecated in the newer versions of PHP. You should use mysqli or PDO instead to get rid of unwanted notices.

```
    <?php 
public function __construct() {
    $this->dbConnection = mysql_connect($this->_dbHost,$this->_dbUsername,$this->_dbPassword);

    if (!$this->dbConnection) {
        die('Connection error.');
    } else {
        $db = mysql_select_db($this->databaseName, $this->dbConnection) OR die("database could not select" .mysql_error());
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thnaks Manish, but im still getting database could not selectNo database selected

Comment: check the value of $this->databaseName